# How do I point two domains to the same django page?

Tags: django, nginx, webserver

I have a Django app running a site, abc.com using nginx on the frontend.

The URL: http://abc.com/products/widget shows the widget product page. I would like to also have the URL http://getwidget.com point at the same product page. How can I configure nginx to do this?

My current nginx config is like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name     abc.com;


        location / {
                client_max_body_size 10M;
                proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8200;
        }

        location /static/
        {
            root /home/projects/abc/static;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another server {} something like this:

```
server{
    listen 80; 
    server_name getwidget.com;
    root /path/to/webroot;
}
```

This new server can point to your project as well as the old one. If you hardcoded some urls in your project you will need to correct this.